# Is there a way to infinitely step deeper into an array

Tags: php, arrays

i have the following code

```
foreach($arrayData as $_key_l1 => $_data_l1)
{
    if(is_array($_data_l1))
    {

    }
    else
    {
        switch($_data_l1)
        {
            case '':
                $arrayData[$_key_l1] = null;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

the idea is that when `$arrayData` is passed into the loop, if any element in the array is itself an array it'll step deeper, using the code above, i would copy that into the `if` and replace the `_l1` in the variables with `_l#` where # is the level i'm on, i would also add another `[$_key_l#]`

at the moment i don't expect it to be any deeper than 3 levels however i would like it if it could go though the array without me having to add in code for each level of depth, so i am wondering, is there already a way do to what i'm trying to do but more dynamicly

NOTE: the `switch ... case` is incomplete, so far it just turns blank strings into null

Comment: Why not just use [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/array_walk_recursive)? Maybe this function already does what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use recursive function calls.

Example:

```
function step_array(&$arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
        if (is_array($val)) {
            step_array($val);
        } else {
            // deal with the value
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need to somehow alter your array you can use the & sign to pass the variable by reference.  `function step_array(&$arr)`It would probably also be a tiny bit faster (because referencing is faster than copying the array in memory on each function call)

Comment: Also remember to reference in your foreach, else you will still have the same issue of not using references. `foreach($arr as $key => &$val){ ... }`

Answer (score 1):

you can use the built in function of php named array_walk_recursive()

here is the tutorial link

[array_walk_recursive()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)